# TV Trope where the first words spoken of a scene are the exact same as the last words of the previous scene

Tags: trope

Is there a TV Trope that describes where the beginning dialogue of a scene is the exact same as the last words spoken in the most previous scene?

Often, the beginning dialogue of the second scene occurs almost immediately after the shot begins, to reinforce the consistency between the two scenes.

And then, occasionally, the dialogue will be exactly the same, but differ in only one word (usually the two statements between scenes will completely oppose each other, in instances like this). Though, I'm not sure if this would be a second trope or not, since the dialogue isn't *exactly* the same..

Comment: Uhm...why in the world does this have a CV on it for being an ID question?

Comment: @steelersquirrel, my guess is because it's asking to identify a trope. If I'm not mistaken, all ID questions are off topic

Comment: That said, I am reminded of [the missile scene from Austin Powers](https://youtu.be/Ju1UwmgkKgI). Is this the trope your asking about?

Comment: @Gnemlock You might be mistaken in the sense that the ID close-reason doesn't actually apply to all kinds of things people would like identified rather than just the ones that were once on-topic and are now off-topic. I also often see it misused for song identification, too, which never counted as an ID question to begin with rather than having other close-reasons that better fit it. Neither have we ever explicitly talked about trope identification at any point. So yes, all ID questions are off-topic, but your definition of "ID question" might be a little broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ironic Echo Cut](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IronicEchoCut)

[Twisted Echo Cut](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwistedEchoCut)

And links therein.

The visual version is a [Match Cut](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MatchCut).